# is it possible to add class to a pseudo element?

Tags: javascript, css

I guess not as this is not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
 $("p:after").addClass("allgone");
</script>
<style type="text/css">
p:after {
 content: "daniel";
}
.allgone{
display: none;
}
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z7TRD/)

Comment: Pseudo-elements are pseudo-elements. They aren't really elements, nor do they function like them. They are rendered via CSS.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, but you can add the class to the `p` element, and create an alternate style for it.

```
p:after {
    content: "daniel";
}
p.allgone:after {
    display: none;
}
```

---

```
$('p').addClass('allgone');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xGUaY/

Comment: That was a long search before reaching this answer, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No, pseudo elements are not part of the DOM, and they can not be accessed via JavaScript.

I believe they are part of the [*Shadow DOM*](http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/). The pseudo element is rendered by the browser as an inline element inside of the containing element, either as the first or last child.

Answer (score 0):

No Since they are pseudo elements and not an actual DOM . 
But you can do play with the class added, like say if  you added the class `box`
then you can do `.box:after` and `.box:before` or `.box::after` and `.box::before` depending on the version you are coding.