# Adding CSS class on pseudo-element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I was wondering if there's a way to add a CSS class to pseudo-elements, such as :after.

I want to use :after to append an error message.  I also want the error message styled the same way as the other error messages.

This works:

```
.error:after {
  content: "Error Message";
  color: red;
}
```

But can I do something like this to add more than the color styling?:

```
.error:after {
  content: "Error Message";
  class: error_message_styles;
}
```

Also, is there a difference between using "::after" vs ":after"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There's no way to give an HTML attribute of any kind to a psuedo element.

Just use the selector twice:

```
.error:after {
  content: "Error Message";
}
.error:after, .error-style {
  color:red;
}
```

> Also, is there a difference between using "::after" vs ":after"?

According to this:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:after
>
> The `::after` notation was introduced in CSS 3 in order to establish a
>   discrimination between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. Browsers
>   also accept the notation `:after` introduced in CSS 2.
>
> **Note:**  Microsoft Internet Explorer 8 supports the :after notation
>   only.

I would argue that error messages might be content, not decoration - but that's your call.

Comment: For me this wasn't the correct solution, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202565/2901207

Answer (score 9):

The `:after` element is not a physical DOM element, so it can't take a class.

If you use a stylesheet library like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/#synopsis), you can mix in the styles from other classes by including the class as a property:

```
.error {
    .error-styles;
}
```